# cv_bridge and OpenCV 2.3.2

Tags: opencv, cv-bridge, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
im using ROS Electric [installed from sources](http://answers.ros.org/question/2554/rosserial-installation) and OpenCV from svn and its has version 2.3.2
but if im trying to make cv_bridge

```
rosmake cv_bridge
```

it want to use 2.3.1:

```
Package opencv-2.3.1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

How could i use OpenCV 2.3.2 instead of 2.3.1?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11735/cv_bridge-and-opencv-2.3.2/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way that works for me consists in:

1. Copying the ROS OpenCV package somewhere. You may renamed this new package to something like opencv232.
2. Changing the Makefile so it downloads the last svn version.
3. Then rosmake -i (remove ROS_NOBUILD fisrt).

For cv_bridge:

1. Copy cv_bridge
2. Rename (opcional)
3. Change manifest dependency to opencv232
4. rosmake -i

Maybe not so clean, but it works.

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-11-01**:
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this [answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/2319/failed-package-compiles-cant-find-opencv-on-debian) help me:

> Sometimes the ROS package might be
> looking for a particular .pc filename,
> like "opencv-2.3.pc", when your build
> of opencv 2.3 only placed a
> "opencv.pc" file there. Then, my
> solution is to create a symbolic link,
> in this case from "opencv.pc" to
> "opencv-2.3.pc" in the relevant
> pkgconfig path.

my actions:

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv-2.3.1.pc
```

edit opencv-2.3.1.pc and change  2.3.2 on 2.3.1

check:

```
pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --cflags
pkg-config opencv-2.3.1 --libs
```

and

```
rosmake cv_bridge
```

it make ok, but with warning:

> [ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not
> detect the following system
> dependencies as installed: opencv2.3
> Consider using --rosdep-install option
> or `rosdep install c v_bridge`

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2